# Regular expression to get a number after particular string in R

Tags: r, regex

I want to extract the numbers following a particular string.

How can I do this in R using regular expression?

Example: In a given string how can I extract the number 2016 after the word "year" . These are some of the possible cases of occurrence of the year and 2016 combinations.

```
<p>Year:2016</p>
<p> year-2016 </p>
<p> year: 2016 </p>
<p>Year : 2016</p>
<p> year - 2016</p>
<p>YEAR : 2016</p>
```

Comment: Did you try to write something yourself?

Comment: I tried to use the regular expression - "\b(?:(\d+)[-\s][Yy]ear|(?:[Y]ear)\s?(?:of\s)?(\d+))" but it doesn't seem to work for all cases.

Comment: @Shivraj It would help if you provide an actual string example.

Comment: So did mine not work for you?

Comment: @hwnd  People talk about the year-2016 being a particularly disastrous year, but for a historian, there’s nothing new about people fighting for power or useless leaders with bad ideas gathering widespread support. 

Here if I want to extract 2016 how can I do it?

Comment: @onzinsky: Thanks it worked, but I was looking for more general case where the year wouldn't be the same in every place

Comment: You're welcome. In the line I gave you, thou, it doesn't matter what year you're looking for. If you have a string with a year in it, this will get the year for you. If you have 2 years in the string it wouldn't be useful.

Comment: @Shivraj ok I just got it. I misunderstood the question a bit. My fault.

Answer (score 1):

Use gsub:

```
gsub(x = "year:-2016", pattern = "[^0-9]", replacement = "")
```

Here you replace everything but numbers with an empty string. If you need a number you can use `as.numeric` function.

Answer (score 0):

In general, a regex expression like this would match: `year[^0-9]*[0-9]{4}`

- You'll need to set case-insensitive option for `year` to match also `yEar` etc.
- It matches when a set of four numbers `[0-9]{4}` that follows the word `year`.
- It's also possible to have any other characters between `year` and the set of four numbers EXCEPT for more numbers `[^0-9]*`.

So this will match all your test cases.

```
<p>Year:2016</p>
<p> year-2016 </p>
<p> year: 2016 </p>
<p>Year : 2016</p>
<p> year - 2016</p>
<p>YEAR : 2016</p>
```

**Thanks to @MatthewLundberg's comment about the inability to simply capture sections of matches in R**, a possible solution may be to first `grep` the pattern `year[^0-9]*[0-9]{4}` to extract the string that includes the pattern, and then extract just the `[0-9]{4}` pattern.

Comment: The expression is not correct for this purpose, as you can't easily just grab the captured value in R.