# R regular expression to identify number after specific string

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I found a previous post that was not flexible enough to apply to my situation...
[Regular expression to get a number after particular string in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40964160/regular-expression-to-get-a-number-after-particular-string-in-r)

What I am trying to do, it to clean up addresses before geocoding them.
For example, I want to remove all PO-box information. In order to do this, I need to be able to idenify the number behind a string that suggests PO box.

```
df <- data.frame(Address = c("123 Fake street, Melbourne, 3000",
                       "PO box 2 123 Fake street, Melbourne, 3000", 
                       "PO box 22313 123 Fake street, Melbourne, 3000", 
                       "PObox 213 Unit 12 123 Fake street, Melbourne, 3000", 
                       "123 Fake street PO box 22313, Melbourne, 3000"))

df$Address <- as.character(df$Address)



> df
                                             Address
1                   123 Fake street, Melbourne, 3000
2          PO box 2 123 Fake street, Melbourne, 3000
3      PO box 22313 123 Fake street, Melbourne, 3000
4 PObox 213 Unit 12 123 Fake street, Melbourne, 3000
5      123 Fake street PO box 22313, Melbourne, 3000
```

I'd like all addresses to be returned as '123 Fake street, Melbourne, 3000'.

As you can see,

- PO box can be spelled various ways
- the number behind PO box varies in length
- PO box section could appear anywhere in the string
- there are other numbers in the string (house number, unit number, postcode, etc)

Comment: What have you been using?

Comment: Do you have any other patterns

Comment: I have not been using anything so far, because I can only clean up when I can remove the 'PO box' string including the 'number' behind the string.

Comment: I think I have covered all patterns so far, but you never know re data entry! Anything can happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gsub("( ){0,1}PO( ){0,1}box [0-9]+( Unit [0-9]+){0,1}( ){0,1}","",df$Address)
```

That workded for me for your exemple.

The `( )` have been kept for simplier conception and reading.

Comment: That is awesome! I just realized I actually want to keep the Unit + number, but see that the following works  for that: gsub("( ){0,1}PO( ){0,1}box [0-9]+( ){0,1}","",df$Address)

Comment: Could you give an explanation on how to 'read' the regex parameters? It would help me, and perhaps others who read this later

Comment: the stuff inside parenthesis will be handle as is for the regexp indication
{0,1} means that the motif (the thing before { in our case () ) have to be found at least 0 time (it can be absent) to reapeated at most 1 time (present)
[0-9]+ any successive number word
the ( ){0,1}  at the extremities are for the case where your PO box are inside your string and are preceded or followed by a space